# Which way is better, setInterval() or window.setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

Ok so there is a couple things to this question.

First of all, i'm asking this for setTimeout() and for setInterval()

I have seen a couple different ways to call them and i'm wondering which way is the best for this circumstance..

I'm making a js/canvas game and I'm just looking over my draw interval (where it loops the draw method)

Anyways, here are the different ways I have seen...

**Part A:**

1. Using window.

   ```
   drawInterval = window.setInterval(draw, 60);
   ```
2. Not using window.

   ```
   drawInterval = setInterval(draw, 60);
   ```

**Part B:**

1. Not using quotes and brackets around the function name

   ```
   drawInterval = setInterval(draw, 60);
   ```
2. Using quotes and brackets around the function name

   ```
   drawInterval = setInterval("draw()", 60);
   ```

So for **Part A:** should i use window. or not?
And what about window.clearInterval() vs clearInterval by itself?

And for **Part B:** should I use quotes and brackets or not? I was told before that it was a bad idea to use quotes and brackets for this situation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Unless you've declared your own locally scoped `setInterval` function, there's no difference between `setInterval` and `window.setInterval`.
2. The second form uses an implied `eval()`.  This should be avoided when possible because it presents the potential for code injection.

Comment: OK, now what about clearInterval(), do I have to use window.clearInterval()? I assume no..

Comment: @Jake - you're correct in that assumption.  The same "Unless you've declared a locally scoped version" statement applies to all of the members of `window`.  setInterval, setTimeout, clearInterval, clearTimeout, etc.

Comment: Um, wouldn't `window.setInterval()` be faster? Since the JS engine would first have to look in all the _other_ scopes before it reaches the window scope? /Remebers an old Google video about that issue./

Comment: @with-a-dot - If you can find a reference I'd be happy to review it.  In general, if the _minor_ improvement that may gain you is critical to your application you have a design implementation flaw somewhere else.

Comment: @gddc Hmm, I wasn't sure; that's why I asked! It was a more of a hypotetical question, but now I'm curious. I might do some tests later. :)

Comment: @gddc, im just wondering, since window. is not really needed, i wouldn't need to use it for say... localStorage()? So instead of window.localStorage, i could just access it via localStorage by itself. I assume this is right, and that this window. rule applies to pretty much everything then?

Comment: @Jake - That is correct, yes.  If you declare your own variable called localStorage within a function its values will be retrieved.  If you did not redeclare it the interpreter will look up the "Scope Chain" until it reaches the top level scope (window) and finds what it needs.  Here's an article that discusses it further:  http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Comment: Might I add a second reason to avoid summoning `eval()` being the huge performance impact it causes (specially important in a rendering loop code).

Comment: using `window.setInterval` is useful when using `jshint` since you then only have to specify one global object (`window`) to gain access to all of its functions.

Comment: So if I override `setInterval() = (...args) => {...}`, the `window.setInterval()` will remain untouched?

Comment: @Ωmega - Yes.  If you define your own `setInterval` in a local scope, you can use it while still using `window.setInterval` elsewhere by referencing it explicitly.  If you assign something different to `window.setInterval` you could inadvertently cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: @g.d.d.c - When I open DevTool console and type `setInterval = 1` [Enter] and then type `window.setInterval` [Enter], it shows `1`, although I expected to see `ƒ setInterval() { [native code] }`

Answer (score 5):

1. `window` is the [global object](http://jonathanfine.wordpress.com/2009/07/17/explicit-use-of-javascripts-global-object/). Whether or not you use it explicitly is something of a matter of style, but as a Python developer, I think explicit is better.
2. If you use quotes, the setInterval() essentially "evals" the statement. [That's bad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx). Don't use the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

`window.setInterval()` and `setInterval()` are exactly the same - the `window` part is implicit and can be omitted.

both setTimeout and setInterval will  eval a string, but best practice is to sent a reference to the function - therefore no quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The calls in part A are the same (unless you redeclare one of those functions somewhere). It comes down to preference- I prefer to leave off `window` as it's unnecessary.

For part B, option 1 is definitely the better practice. Option 2 is going to `eval` that string, and `eval` should almost always be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

As for prefixing it with `window.`, there's not a lick of difference.  You can use either.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the `window.setInterval` vs just `setInterval`

But, it's better to always pass a function, rather than string to setInterval and setTimeout

Comment: @Jake, yes, and as mentioned by others `window.setInterval` and `setInterval` are effectively the same, `window.setInterval` is just more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Another good reason to use `window.setTimeout` instead of just `setTimeout` is that it allows you to give just a single declaration to `jshint` of which global objects your code depends on:

```
/*global window */
```

thus allowing access to all of the `window` methods without having to specify each of them individually in your `jshint` directives.